# can't use uniform initialization in constructor initialization list with try/catch

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, uniform-initialization

The [following code](http://ideone.com/q3R4jW) does not compile with gcc:

```
struct test {
    int x;
    test() try : x{123} {
    }
    catch (...) {
    }
};

int main() {}
```

Errors:

```
prog.cpp:3:25: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
     test() try : x{123} {
                         ^
prog.cpp:5:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘catch’
     catch (...) {
     ^
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘test::test()’:
prog.cpp:3:23: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
     test() try : x{123} {
                       ^
prog.cpp:3:23: error: expected ‘catch’ at end of input
prog.cpp:3:23: error: expected ‘(’ at end of input
prog.cpp:3:23: error: expected type-specifier at end of input
prog.cpp:3:23: error: expected ‘)’ at end of input
prog.cpp:3:23: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
```

Changing `x{123}` to `x(123)` helps. Is this supposed to (not) work this way?

Comment: Clang [compiles it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e8921393e3a52f1) without errors

Comment: Anything to do with braces and C++11 is very likely to have incompletely implemented corner cases in compilers for some time...

Comment: @KerrekSB I thought it's a bug initially, but in Stroustrup's book he uses uniform initialization in constructors, except when there is a try/catch, so that kinda puzzled me.

Comment: Intel C++ 13.1.3 compiles it without errors too.

Comment: gcc mainline compiles it.

Comment: @chill Must've been a bug in the current version then? I think you should post it as an answer...

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using? Did you turn on the C++11 flag?

Comment: @texasbruce http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04a0025c4faac9eb `g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic`

Comment: @catscradle Just tried in my gcc 4.7.2, and you are right it is not working. I would think it is a bug.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not a gcc bug tracker.

Comment: @KubaOber 99% of the times (and I'd say quite a lot more) where you have code that doesn't work though you think it should, the reason is that you made a mistake, not a compiler bug. I think this is a very fair question, even if it eventually turns out that the reason is a compiler bug.

Comment: @Gorpik: Once it's know that it's a compiler bug, it's time to close the question. It was fair once, but no more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid according to the grammar of the standard (see [gram.special] for the braces, and [gram.except] for `try`-`catch`.  GCC 4.8 has it wrong, but GCC 4.9 handles it properly (as do other compilers, as already reported).

I have no idea why BS does not use this syntax in his book.  Maybe because he didn't have any compiler at hand that supported this syntax when he compiled his examples to see if they are right (if he did)?